# STL support in Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Anyone heard of a good standard template library in Ruby? Or any wrapper exists?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean? Are you referring to the C++ STL?

Comment: yes, C++ STL and thanks for clarifications from you guys on the built-in capability of Ruby. cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to something like the C++ STL, then this is largely built in to Ruby already. Ruby has a large suite of basic data structures and other utilities.

Answer (score 3):

As in, C/C++ STL support? All of the functionality is there. You have **Strings**, **Integers** (can take on any value, not limited to 2<sup>32</sup> (int), 2<sup>64</sup> (long), etc.), **Arrays**, **Hashes** and etc. When you want a **Queue** or a **Stack** just use an array using the `push`, `pop`, `delete_at(0)`. Iterations can be done with

```
some_array.each { |x| 
    #some action
}
```

Comment: perfectly good answer, no need to put it into comment. But you have to learn formatting.